# redis service fails with permission denied on append file

Tags: redis

My redis service (installed from source) fails with this message in `/var/log/redis.log`

```
2309:C 16 Mar 2019 20:16:10.633 # Redis version=5.0.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=2309, just started
2309:C 16 Mar 2019 20:16:10.633 # Configuration loaded
2311:M 16 Mar 2019 20:16:10.634 # Can't open the append-only file: Permission denied
```

**However**:

```
root@redis:~# sudo su - redis
redis@redis:~$ touch /var/lib/redis/foobar.txt
redis@redis:~$ echo $?
0
```

Here is my `/etc/redis.conf`

```
root@redis:~# cat /etc/redis.conf 
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
dir /var/lib/redis
daemonize yes
logfile "/var/log/redis.log"
```

and here is my custom unit file for redis

```
root@redis:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/redis.service 
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store                       
After=network.target                                         

[Service]                                                    
Type=forking                                                 
User=redis                                                   
Group=redis                                                                                
PermissionsStartOnly=true                                                              
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
ExecStart=/opt/redis-stable/src/redis-server /etc/redis.conf
Restart=always                                               
RestartSec=3                                                 
LimitNOFILE=65535
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis
ReadOnlyDirectories=/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/run/redis



[Install]                                                    
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The redis starts as non-root service so you need to adjust the permissions of your data directory before starting service.

You just need to execute this command:

```
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 redis-data/
```

And restart redis

Comment: which user is 1001? Why 1001?

Comment: @ante.sabo You can see user 1001 in bitnami/redis image. If you use other docker image you need to find the uer id in similar way. https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis/blob/master/6.0/debian-11/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

-known issue https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8172
-I have still not been able to figure out how to get it working on kubernetes

Comment: You need to run initContainer with command `['sh', '-c', "until telnet <redis-service-name>.<k8s-user-namespace> 6379; do echo waiting for redis; sleep 1; done"]`

Answer (score 0):

The error is that redis can't write the append only file. By default the append only file is placed in the directory where redis is launched from.

My guess is that the redis user does not have write access in the location being launched from. Just make sure that you launch redis from a woring directory that the redis user has access to.

To read more about the AOF file, check the documentation: http://redis.io/topics/persistence.

Comment: But I have instructed redis via the directive `dir /var/lib/redis` in `/etc/redis.conf` to place there the append only file; and as `redis` user I managed to create a file there;

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know, but it's certainly a file permissions error. Try changing the `dir` directive to somewhere else and also try starting in a different directory.